# Boolean not updating from button click in Next.js dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, next.js, boolean

I am creating a dashboard with a lot of 'control' buttons that update a mongoDB database. Most of my buttons function properly, but I am having trouble with a simple toggle button called 'Standby', pressed once standby is on, pressed again standby is off and the database is updated.

Here is the html for the button, the id and the current standby state is passed into the standByButton function.

```
<form action={standByButton}>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value={staff.id} />
   <input type="hidden" name="isStandBy" value={staff.standBy} />
   <StandByButton type={"submit"}/>
</form>
```

Here is the standByButton function. My issue comes from changing the state of the boolean. Here I expect it to reverse every time the button is pressed, but the state does not change with `const standBy = !isStandBy;`. In fact it works elsewhere in my script, but not here. I have confirmed that the database is updated with each call, but `standBy` does not change state.

```
export const standByButton = async (formData) => {
    const { id, isStandBy } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
 
    const standBy = !isStandBy;


    try {
        connectToDB();

        const updateFields = {
            standBy
        }

        console.log(updateFields);

        await Daily.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateFields);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to update standby");
    }

    revalidatePath("/dashboard/board");
}
```

I have tried two methods currently to change the boolean. I have tried `const standBy = !isStandBy;` which did not work. I also tried changing the state after `updatedFields` has been created.

```
export const standByButton = async (formData) => {
    const { id, isStandBy } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
 
    const standBy = !isStandBy;

    try {
        connectToDB();
        const updateFields = {
            standBy
        }

        Object.keys(updateFields).forEach(
            (key) =>
               (parseInt(updateFields[key]) == true) ? (updateFields[key] = false) :
               (parseInt(updateFields[key]) == false) && (updateFields[key] = true)
        )

        console.log(updateFields);
        await Daily.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateFields);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to update standby");
    }

    revalidatePath("/dashboard/board");
}
```

This method did not work either. I have checked that the form is being passed correctly, and the database is being updated correctly, so the error must be with the boolean state change but I can't pin point exactly what is causing it. I have also tried changing the the type of variable by using `let standBy = !isStandBy;` but it still does not change the outcome.

Comment: As long as the function will not be recreated each time, `standBy` cannot be change after initialization because it is declared `const`.